# asp.net pagination code samples

Tags: asp.net, pagination

I need some asp.net pagination code samples.

I would like suggestions on open source apps from where I can pick up code.

I would like suggestions different open source apps for different techniques and if possible give hints on the technique used.

Comment: at least try a serach engine first...

Comment: This question would be easier to answer if you added what type of control/view you want to add the pagination too. Are we talking about a Grid, a Repeater, etc.? The Grid for example, has built-in pagination functionality.

Comment: i don't want to use datagrid.I guess it may bloat the app.

Comment: i would use a repeater cause then you got design creativity to it.. i made a paging with numbers not long ago. you can take a look at my code i posted over at asp.net

http://forums.asp.net/t/1479640.aspx

Comment: http://WhatHaveYouTried.com We are volunteers who want to help you with a specific problem. We donate our time; donate some of yours and show that you at least tried **something**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a few to get you started:

- [Paging In ASP.NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020135845/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/091003-1.aspx)
- [Paging Database Results in ASP.NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20161107163939/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/ASPScripts/PrintPage.asp?REF=/webtech/072101-1.shtml)
- [Custom Paging in ASP.NET 2.0 with SQL Server 2005](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020140032/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031506-1.aspx)